Firebase Hosting Issue with Vue2.js
So i have been hosting my vue project using firebase hosting and recently
it stopped working. I get back a white screen with these errors on the live url Log
The stylesheet https://hodl-f3ae3.web.app/css/chunk-vendors.bc3d01bb.css was not loaded because            its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”. hodl-f3ae3.web.app
The stylesheet https://hodl-f3ae3.web.app/css/app.c222e160.css was not loaded because its MIME   type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”. hodl-f3ae3.web.app
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
chunk-vendors.c2b01f1b.js:1:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

I have no clue what the issue could be
i have deleted the dist and rebuilt
All my config files seem fine
there is nothing different i have done that i have been doing
but for some reason it stopped working
any ideas what the issue could be ?
I am trying to host my Vue2 project on firebase hosting
it always works but for some reasons it stopped and on the logs i get back this
The stylesheet https://hodl-f3ae3.web.app/css/chunk-vendors.bc3d01bb.css was not loaded because    its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”. hodl-f3ae3.web.app
The stylesheet https://hodl-f3ae3.web.app/css/app.c222e160.css was not loaded because its MIME   type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”. hodl-f3ae3.web.app
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
chunk-vendors.c2b01f1b.js:1:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'


Besides the fact that you should not be using Vue2 anymore + NodeJS latest version being bumped to v20, the error is definitely indicative of the fact that the server supposedly responsible for the app run on the hosting platform is not running. Try to host if on Netlify for troubleshooting purposes. Overall, lots of things could still be missing but this is a decent starting point.
